# Python script to read http paramters from a file

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to extract the information from twitter http responses.
I have collated a list of infosec professionals on twitter, but i want to extract their description through an automated way - preferrably python script.

The HTTP request is like https://twitter.com/bpiatt

so my request in the code : urllib2.urlopen("https://twitter.com/$variable").read()

where variable is the name in the file that has the list of names.

The issues i have is how to store the names in a variable and then make the http request.

I can extract the description field once i have done this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
urllib2.urlopen("https://twitter.com/%s" % variable).read()
```